# Throws, reading from files, and File

Tags: java, exception, io

I'm having a little trouble understand what this method signature means:

```
public Maze(File f) throws Exception {
```

It is supposed to read in String mazes from a file.

From my understanding, it is a constructor for Maze, that takes in a File f... any suggestions/help are appreciated :)

Comment: Without the code, there is no possible answer to that. Also, using `File` in 2016 is like using an ox cart on the road: it makes no sense

Comment: it's for an assignment, I can't modify the method signature.

Comment: Your final paragraph is correct.  What else do you want clarified?  (Also, start going through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ — you will be glad you did.)